# Parse the flat file in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to parse the csv file data which contains tag data to columns heades and values in Tableau.

I have tried in the tableau desktop..

I did tried with Spilt function..

```
1,{
"StudentLocs":["US","Kric"],
"Student_Service":["NY Volunteer"],
"Student_Unit":["Band1"],
"Student_enZone":["UTC"],
"Student_Geoloc":["Ind"],
"StudentRegisted":[FT"],
"StudentGender":["Male"],
"StudentName":["Sam"]
}

Expected output:

SId SLocs   SService     SUnit SenZone SGeoloc SRegisted SGender SName
1   US,Kric NY Volunteer Band1  UTC     Ind      FT       Male    Sam
```

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: My personal choice would be to first preprocess this data with another tool or script into a "normal" csv layout (one row with header and other rows with comma seperated values) and then import it in Tableau.